# Exposing Action-Specific Data to Custom Authorization Policies in ASP.NET Core using ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authorization

I am using an approach (i think is a hack) to pass values to make Action-specific permission data available to custom authorization policy.

The Problem?
I needed a way to pass Action-Specific data to authorization requirement handlers.

I **did not want** to do this in Startup

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {               
            options.AddPolicy("MyPolicy",policy =>policy.Requirements.Add(new PermissionRequirement(PermissionEnum.CanView)));
        });
```

And This in Controller

```
[Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
public IActionResult MyAction()
    {          
        return View();
    }
```

Because it would require me to have too many policies since i have a lot of permissions. So i needed to be able to pass `PermissionEnum.CanView` to the authorization handler at the action level so that i can specify what permission is required for each action and have the same handler handle them.

I could not figure out a way to pass value to the policy attribute so i did this instead. I created an a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` and passed the values there

```
public class AccessAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Permission { get; }

    public AccessAttribute(PermissionEnum permission)
    {
        Permission =  permission.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then I Used it like so

```
[Access(PermissionEnum.CanView)]
[Authorize(Policy = "MyPolicy")]
public IActionResult MyAction()
{          
    return View();
}
```

Then in the authorization handler I access this value from the `AuthorizationHandlerContext` object like so

```
var mvcContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
var descriptor = mvcContext?.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

if (descriptor == null) return Task.CompletedTask;

foreach (var filterMetadata in mvcContext.Filters)
{
if (filterMetadata.GetType().Name != typeof(AccessAttribute).Name) continue;

var PermissionAttribute = filterMetadata as AccessAttribute;

if (PermissionAttribute == null) continue;
if (context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == PermissionAttribute.Permission))
{
context.Succeed(requirement);
}
}   

return Task.CompletedTask;
```

Here i have given the users in context permissions in the form of claims and so i check if the user has the indicated permission on the action. The bottom line is that i can tell which users can access an action by setting the permission as an attribute in my custom filter.

Everything works fine but I want to know if this is the way to go. I assume there might be a better approach to doing this or even a way to pass values to the custom policy.

Questions:

1) Is there a better approach that this?

2) I noticed from debugging that my each custom filter runs twice at the start. This may not be a problem but i just wonder why `twice`. They dont run anytime an action is accessed (This is fine by me though) since its a hard  code and will not vary no matter how many times the action is executed. I am just wondering about these but my first question is my actual concern.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT]** Answer based on "traditional" ASP.NET MVC and can be easily adapted to ASP.NET Core MVC.

> So i needed to be able to pass PermissionEnum.CanView to the authorization handler at the action level so that i can specify what permission is required for each action and have the same handler handle them.

An option is to create a custom AuthorizeAttribute that receives the permission in its constructor:

```
public class CustomAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly string _permission = "";

    // use your Enum instead of string        
    public CustomAuthorization(string permission) : base()
    {
        _permission = permission;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (_permission == "xxx" && Roles.Contains("yyyy"))
        {
            // do something interesting
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And its usage:

```
    [CustomAuthorization("My Permission", Roles = "MyRoles")]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Is this for ASP.NET Core ?

Comment: No, it is not Asp.Net Core. The question was marked as Asp.net Core and Asp.Net MVC. I did't see the "core part" and I ended up responding based on ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft-endorsed technique for accomplishing what you want to do is to implement a custom authorization policy provider.  The basic idea is that you would have a separate policy name for each possible scenario (e.g. `MyPolicy_CanView`, etc.), but you wouldn't register each of those; your custom authorization policy provider would be invoked each time an action method with an authorize attribute is called, and it would see that the policy name matches a given pattern (e.g. starts with MyPolicy_ in this example) and then creates a policy on the fly using your one requirement and the parameter which it extracted from the name (e.g. CanView in this example).  You can also use a custom attribute to build the policy name if you don't want the custom name (MyPolicy_CanView) appearing in your controller code.

Here is the Microsoft documentation with the details and sample code:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/iauthorizationpolicyprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Hackernoon describes the technique but implements the custom policy provider by deriving from DefaultAuthorizationPolicyProvider instead of implementing IAuthorizationPolicyProvider:  https://hackernoon.com/permission-based-authorization-asp-net-core-with-authorizationpolicyprovider-af4933d575ee